# Vue-Apollo V4 composition API @vue/apollo-composable on loginform. TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Ref<any>' has no call signatures

Tags: vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo, vue-composition-api

I am a new one in the apollo world. I use Vue composition API and `@vue/apollo-composable` with version V4 for my vue apollo client. And the backend is nodejs server with apollo server.

Now I have a problem on the login page with `useQuery`, if I call the result of the query, they will be show the error

> TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Ref' has no call signatures

```ts
import { ref, defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { useUserLogin } from '@/mixins/user-login'
import { CustomRules } from '@/validators/rules'
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const form = ref()
    const rules = ref(CustomRules)
    const username = ref('')
    const password = ref('')
    const errorMessage = ref('')

    const { result: loginBenutzer } = useQuery(gql`
      query loginBenutzer($kuerzel: String!, $passwort: String!) {
        loginBenutzer(kuerzel: $kuerzel, passwort: $passwort) {
          user {
            kuerzel: BEN_MIA_KUERZEL,
            name: BEN_NAME
          },
          token
        }
      }
    `)

    function login() {
      if (form.value.validate()) {
        loginBenutzer({ kuerzel: username.value, passwort: password.value })
          .then(data => {
            useUserLogin(data.data.loginBenutzer)
            root.$router.push('/hm')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            errorMessage.value = err.message
            console.log(err)
          })
      }
    }

    return {
      form,
      rules,
      username,
      password,
      login,
      errorMessage,
    }
  },
})
```

Calling to result: `loginBenutzer` of this line

```ts
loginBenutzer({ kuerzel: username.value, passwort: password.value })
```

the `loginBenutzer` shows the error:

> TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Ref' has no call signatures

And in the Apollo server type is defined like this

```ts
type Query {
    loginBenutzer(kuerzel: String!, passwort: String!): LoginResponse!,
}
```

but if I change the query to mutation, then they are working. Like this

```ts
    const { mutate: loginBenutzer } = useMutation(gql`
      mutation loginBenutzer($kuerzel: String!, $passwort: String!) {
        loginBenutzer(kuerzel: $kuerzel, passwort: $passwort) {
          user {
            kuerzel: BEN_MIA_KUERZEL,
            name: BEN_NAME
          },
          token
        }
      }
    `)

    function login() {
      if (form.value.validate()) {
        loginBenutzer({ kuerzel: username.value, passwort: password.value })
          .then(data => {
            useUserLogin(data.data.loginBenutzer)
            root.$router.push('/hm')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            errorMessage.value = err.message
            console.log(err)
          })
      }
    }
```

and the type like this

```ts
type Mutation {
    loginBenutzer(kuerzel: String!, passwort: String!): LoginResponse!,
}
```

but I am very sure, the `useQuery` for the calling of user information is a right way.

Answer (score 0):

> result: result data object.

As [documentation](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-query.html#parameters) said,`result` return result data object, which will be a Ref type,

> refetch(variables?): Execute the query again, optionally with new
> variables.

Try `refetch` instead if you want to pass new variables